# what are string literal in postgres as function argument

Tags: postgresql

so for the below code what is "table" and "column", how are they different if I just put int table and column as variable name

```
create type MatchingRecord as ("table" text, "column" text, nexamples integer);

create or replace function Q2("table" text, pattern text)
    returns setof MatchingRecord
as $$
  begin
  end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

`"table"` is not a "string literal", it's an identifier - the name of the parameter.

Strings require **single** quotes, e.g. `'table'` would be a string.

Because `table` and `column` are reserved keywords those parameter names (identifiers) need to be quoted and that is done using double quotes in SQL.

Details in the manual
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: so if I want to refer to that parameter in the function do I write select * from table? or select * from "table"?